# Flutter drawer, app bar arrow showing after pulling drawer

Tags: flutter, dart, navigation, drawer, appbar

I added drawer to my project using endDrawer for it to be placed to the right. When I pull the drawer, the app bar arrow is showing and pushing other app bar contents to the right.

Already searched some threads. I used Navigator.pushReplacement(...) to get to the dashboard. Tried making the dashboard the home page as well because I thought it was a navigation thing but to no avail
!

```
endDrawer: Drawer(
        child: ListView(
          padding: EdgeInsets.zero,
          children: <Widget>[
            Container(
              height: 300,
              child: DrawerHeader(
                child: Column(
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                  children: <Widget>[
                    Padding(
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                      child: Image.asset(
                        "assets/avatar.png",
                        width: 90,
                      ),
                    ),
                    Padding(
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(5.0),
                      child: Text("Sample Name",
                          style: TextStyle(
                              fontSize: 20,
                              fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                              color: Colors.white)),
                    ),
                    Text("sample@mail.com",
                        style: TextStyle(fontSize: 16, color: Colors.white)),

                    // Text()
                  ],
                ),
                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                  color: Colors.blueAccent,
                ),
              ),
            ),
            ListTile(
              leading: Icon(Icons.info),
              title: Text('About'),
              onTap: () {
                // Update the state of the app
                // ...
                // Then close the drawer
                Navigator.pop(context);
              },
            ),
            ListTile(
              leading: Icon(Icons.lock),
              title: Text('Privacy Policy'),
              onTap: () {
                // Update the state of the app
                // ...
                // Then close the drawer
                Navigator.pop(context);
              },
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
```

I need to remove the arrow showing on the app bar

Comment: Your code got bad formatation, please adjust so we can help. And provide an image of the situation that will help us to see the problem. Thanks

Comment: set `automaticallyImplyLeading` in appbar  to `false`

Comment: That fixed my problem anmol.majhail. Thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

in your AppBar insert this

```
AppBar (
    automaticallyImplyLeading: false,
    ...
)
```